# JTextArea setWrapStyleWord(true) does not work if appending text

Tags: jtextarea, word-boundaries

According to Oracle at [JTextArea documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html), if you wish to wrap lines **AND** wrap at word boundaries and not character boundaries you must use code as follows:

```
jtaOutputPrimes.setLineWrap(true);
jtaOutputPrimes.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Please note that the jtaOutputPrimes is the name of my `JTextArea` on my `JPanel`.
The issue comes in when I use the method append to add text to the JTextArea as follows:

```
jtaOutputPrimes.append(",");
```

In this case, the `setWrapStyleWord` setting does not work.  It continues to use the character boundaries and not the word boundaries.

I have found another person experiencing same issue here:  [setWrapStyleWord issue](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t128377-jtextarea-setwrapstyleword.html)

Now, lets say you are running an `JApplet` that has this `JTextArea`. If you type in the text area, it will word wrap fine, but any passed text from the append method does not work.

I believe this is a bug, and I cannot find Oracle acknowledge it as such anywhere.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found out why this was happening, and this simple fix may be beneficial to others.  The issue came into play because when I appended the comma (,) to the JTextArea it was eliminating the white space between words.  To fix this, I simply placed a space after the comma like so, and it worked.

jtaOutputPrimes.append(", ");